# SQL services Report squashes text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I Have a problem im working on Visual studio 2008 report services. every time i try i print it squashes the text but in designer view everything seems fine. there is nothing wrong with my printer or drivers because other documents print fine this only happens in vs 2008 report services.
cany anyone help?

Before Printing in designer preview
[image]

After printing

[image]

Comment: Does this issue occur when printing to XPS document creator?

Comment: Yes it still does but i used cutepdf writer. to test it.. it has to be something in visual studio or my pc. the printer is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is one strange issue.
Rumor has it that this is caused by someone with a 16:9 aspect ratio monitor logging into SQL Server remotely as the first user.
This sets the aspect ratio for the server and causes printing issues.
The fix is apparently to reboot the server and either log in using a machine with a 4:3 monitor, or with a forced aspect ratio command:

```
mstsc /v:SERVERNAME /admin /w:1024 /h:768 (this forces the needed 4:3 aspect ratio)
```

I can't take credit for this answer, since it came from http://www.hagrin.com/339/sql-reporting-services-fixing-no-letter-spacing-when-printing-problem, but I hope it solves your problem.